# JavaAgent on Java 9

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

Prior to java 9, the monitoring `JavaAgent` were loaded into the JVM by `boostrapClassloader` so that the monitored applications could access them

With Java 9 modular architecture, only `java.base module` gets loaded in Bootstrap classloader and so, Java agent can access only classes inside java.base?
It can't access anything outside java.base by default?

What is required to be changed inside `javaAgent` in order to access other modules like java.sql?

Comment: Do you have an exception or error related to this? Can you add it to question?

Answer (score 4):

I just validated this for the latest build and when using

```
Instrumentation::appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch
```

The class is added to the bootstrap loader (`null`) and loaded into the `unnamed module` of this loader. This is true for Java 9, ea-176.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use the following API

Comment: Instrumentation::appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch() takes the location of jar file. What would be the jar location for java.sql module?

Comment: You can only append a jar file of your own which then runs on the bootstrap class loader. You cannot add a module this way. Are you trying to add the sql module after the application has already started? This is not possible using a Java agent.

Comment: I have an old Java agent packaged as Agent.jar and that jar is added in the Boot-Class-Path in the manifest file. So, this jar will be loaded by BootstrapClassloader.This jar internally refers to classes from java.sql.
On Java 8 since java.sql was part of rt.jar, so, there were no classloader visibility issues.Now on Java 9, Agent.jar is loade by BoostrapClassloader because of manifest entry, but it can't access java.sql because java.sql is loaded by PlatformClassLoader.

Comment: My question was is there any way Agent.jar can still acess java.sql classes on Java 9 or to be more generic how can Agent.jar access classes other than java.base module?

Comment: The Java agent is loaded in the unnamed module of the system class loader. This allows it to read any exported type of any module visible to the system class loader. The `Instrumentation` API was also altered to allow adding exports if you wanted to read additional packages of this module.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused.Earlier JavaAgent was loaded by BootstrapClassloader because of manifest entry(Boot-Class-Path) of JavaAgent.jar.
 Are you saying that on Java9, JAvaAgent is loaded by System Classloader, not by BootstrapClassloader?

Comment: Java agents were never loaded by the bootstrap loader. They always end up on the system class path.

Comment: OK. I had the impression that adding the following in manifest would make sure Agent.jar is loaded in the Bootstrap classloader
Boot-Class-Path: Agent.jar
What you are saying is that Agent.jar was loaded always by System Classloader, but because of the above manifest entry(Boot-Class-Path),Agent.jar was visible to BootstrapClassloader as well, right?

Comment: Maybe you added the same classes to your agent and the boot class jar or even referenced the agent jar as boot jar? The latter won't work in Java 9 as the unnamed modules of the boot and system class loader are different and they cannot share packages. It will likely cause problems on Java 8 too, though. Create two different jars! The boor jar will be available to your agent anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link the java.lang.instrument package description in the JDK 9 EA builds:

http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html

The section "Loading agent classes and the modules/classes available to the agent class" should help with the discussion here.

As regards the java.sql module then it is one of several "non-core" modules that are no longer defined to the boot loader. Moving these modules to the platform class loader means they can run with reduced permissions and so helps with the overall security of the platform. This should be completely transparent to applications and libraries on the class path and should only be noticeable by code that (a) runs with -Xbootclasspath/a, (b) creates a custom class with null as the parent, and (c) agent supporting classes added to the boot class loader search with the Boot-Class-Path attribute or the appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch API.